# Same font is rendered different depending on how it is loaded

Tags: css, sass, fonts, webfonts, renderer

We are developing an application using the [Lato font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato). UI design is made in Figma.

If we load the fonts locally (download the ttf's from google and convert them to woff and woff2) using font face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src: url('~@/assets/fonts/lato-black-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('~@/assets/fonts/lato-black-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: $black;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

it will render them different from figma (which is also loaded in web).

If we load the fonts directly from google cdn using import

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap);
```

it will also render them different from figma and the local load.

All 3 applications (custom app with fonts loaded locally, custom app with fonts loaded from cdn, figma) seem to render the font (specially the font-weight) differently (all 3 apps have the same style property values: font, font-family, font-size, font-weight, etc).

Where does this difference result from?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please explain what you mean with 'differently' and can you add screenshots of the behaviour?

Comment: [Figma]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YplPr.png
  [Font-face-local-woffs]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNfu4.png
  [Import-google-cdn]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wETyw.png

Comment: Different as in different weights, letter aspect.